# Saving time.Time in golang to postgres timestamp with time zone field

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to test my database (which is Postgres) models in golang. the problem is that a field value with time.Time type miss-match when I retrieved it from DB. here is the code:

```
a := myStruct{aTime: time.Now().UTC(), ...}
res, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ($1, $2, ...) RETURNING id", a.aTime, ...)
...
// some logic for setting id in struct a
...
row := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = $1", a.id)
var test *myStruct
row.Scan(test)
reflect.DeepEqual(a, test) // returns False
fmt.Printf("%v\n%v", a, test)
// {2020-02-25 12:37:16.906605805 +0000 UTC ...}
// {2020-02-25 12:37:16.906606 +0000 UTC ...}
```

and the time field type in the database is `timestamp with time zone`.

I tried the following too:

```
a.aTime.Equal(test.aTime) // returns false
a.aTime = a.aTime.Round(time.Second)
test.aTime = test.aTime.Round(time.Second)
a.aTime.Equal(test.aTime) // returns true
```

but still reflect.DeepEqual returns false. the problem is time field, because when i do the following the reflect.DeepEqual turns to true

```
a.aTime = test.aTime
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Don't use `reflect.DeepEqual` to compare times, use `time.Equal()`. If you want to compare TZ's of two times, then you can extract that the TZ with `time.Zone()` or `time.Location()`

Comment: thanks, @colminator
reflect.DeepEqual makes it so simple to compare structs. do you have any simple solution to compare structs containing time fields? I don't want to use an if with 4 lines of conditions.

Comment: `reflect` really should only be used if you are writing a generic framework that anyone will use. `reflect` is also slow. If you have a concrete application with finite type definitions, there really is no need to use it. If you have a complex struct and want to avoid boiler-plate comparison code, then create an `Equal` method once - and avoid the boiler-plate elsewhere.

Comment: `reflect` will give you false negatives, any time timezones are different, or any time the monotonic time is different (which will be virtually every time you initialize time with `time.Now()` or similar.). Avoid reflection _whenever possible_. Example: https://play.golang.org/p/DaPKdY1C-ty

Comment: From: [go-proverbs](http://go-proverbs.github.io/) "[Reflection is never clear](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=15m22s)"

Comment: @colminator tnx!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These times are not equal:

```
// {2020-02-25 12:37:16.906605805 +0000 UTC ...}
// {2020-02-25 12:37:16.906606 +0000 UTC ...}
```

the DB value has (rounded) micro-second precision - go's time has nano-second precision.

I would suggest rounding your times *before* you add them to the database to a level of precision that is supported by your DB and your needs e.g.

```
a.Atime = a.aTime.Round(time.Microsecond) // round to nearest micro (per Markus comment)

res, err := db.Exec("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ($1, $2, ...) RETURNING id", a.aTime, ...)
```

---

Also to compare time equality, use [time.Equal()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal):

> Equal reports whether t and u represent the same time instant. Two
>   times can be equal even if they are in different locations. For
>   example, 6:00 +0200 and 4:00 UTC are Equal. See the documentation on
>   the Time type for the pitfalls of using == with Time values; most code
>   should use Equal instead.

Comment: PostgreSQL only stores with microsecond precision. Another option would be to store a.aTime.UnixNano() as integer field... but then you loose TZ information and need to store that elsewhere, plus, you need to do all the mangling.